# Experimentally Tracking Fluid Flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, flow, experimental-technique

I've been facing this issue and I will be very grateful if anyone could offer insights!

---

I have a stream of water that starts out from a nozzle flowing down vertically. The stream of water hits a plate that is inclined and deflects from it.

I am wondering, is there a way which I can experimentally quantify things like the flow velocity in the leaving stream of water?

Currently, what I have is this:

1. The volumetric flow rate can be measured by taking the time taken to fill a container with known volume via my initial nozzle - by conservation principles, the deflection also does not change the volumetric flow rate.
2. However, what about the flow velocity? I have considered using Q = Av, qualifying the area at each point on the deflected stream to find the velocity there. This doesn't feel very precise or accurate at all, however. How to qualify the area is also an issue.

I have also attached a image of how the system looks like:
[image: Diagram Representing the Problem at hand]

So, does anyone have any insights on this? Thank you!

Comment: Why is the cross sectional area a problem to measure, simply take a picture from two angles with a ruler for scale nearby?!

Comment: You could use some.food colouring to track and measure the fluid.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the fluid's velocity field as function of position on the inclined plate. Hence, you need to track that as function of the two spatial coordinates. To do this, you need to mark your fluid at a given position and time, and then re-evaluate that fluid element's position at a later time. I see no other way.

To mark, I would use food color or little suspended particles such as glitter. To track, I would take pictures at known time intervals.